# Toggle toggles another toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good day everyone,
i'm currently working on my exam project and am building a mobile menu. It's working but sadly closing the menu toggles the search toggle and shows this div while closing the menu, which gets annoying very soon.

my javascript is;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".search").click(function(){
            $(".searchbar").toggle({ direction: "left" }, 500);
        });

        $(".searchmenu").click(function(){
            $(".searchfieldmenu").toggle({ direction: "left" }, 500);
        });

        $(".hamburger").click(function(){
            $(".mobilenavigation").toggle({ direction: "left" }, 500);
            $(".hamburger").toggle({ direction: "left" }, 500);
            $(".hamburgerclose").toggle({ direction: "left" }, 500);
        });

        $(".hamburgerclose").click(function(){
            $(".mobilenavigation").toggle({ direction: "left" }, 500);
            $(".hamburger").toggle({ direction: "left" }, 500);
            $(".hamburgerclose").toggle({ direction: "left" }, 500);
        });
    });
```

a current working example can be found here (I rather not share a pen due to exam regulations, but feel free to inspect!)

https://codepen.io/Puffss/project/editor/DWqbbX/

- Recreate problem;

  - mobile viewport
  - open menu with 75x75 div
  - make sure the searchbar (top item in menu) is closed
  - close menu with 50x50 div next to menu

as the menu closes you'll see the searchbar opening in the top

Comment: ok, if you can show us your HTML code maybe we can help you. But I assume that instead of `$(".mobilenavigation")` in your click handler you have to do something like `$(this).find(".mobilenavigation").toggle({ direction: "left" }, 500)`. It really depends on your HTML

Comment: It's because your hamburger close has a link in it with a class of search - which triggers your searchobx toggle, either stop propogation of the hamburger close click or remove the search class from the link

Comment: `@media screen and (min-width: 900px) and (min-width: 1100px) ` makes no sense. Also There's 2 `@media screen and (min-width: 900px)` and 2 of `@media screen and (min-width: 900px) and (min-width: 1100px) `. You should keep all of your rulesets in the appropriate and unique MQ's

Comment: Remove the last function and modify the 3rd block:`$(".hamburgerclose, .hamburger").click(function(){...`

Comment: I modified the 3rd block, but sadly the problem still exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your links inside `.hamburger` and `.hamburgerclose` have the `.search` class which results in your very first Event Handler being triggered.

**Do the following**

- Remove the `.search` class inside `.hamburger` and `.hamburgerclose`
- Be more specific: replace your `toggle()` with `hide()` and `show()` to know exactly what your functions do

See the working result here:
https://codepen.io/dvdglth/project/editor/AKjwVX/